# Get status of grouping toggle item

Tags: powerbi-paginated-reports

I'd like to get the status of the group "Details" toggle item (+/- Symbol) in Power BI Report Builder (Paginated Reports) as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

The toggle item is located in Textbox A.
The formula
`IIF(InScope("Details"), "Visible", "Hidden")`
works as long as it is in the shown/hidden group rows, but I would like to display the visibility status in the report header. If I place the formula there, the status does not change when the group is shown or hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new measure with the following DAX formula:

```
ToggleStatus =
IF(
    ISFILTERED('Table'[Details]),
    "Visible",
    "Hidden"
)
```

You can use this measure in the report header to display the status of the "Details" toggle item

Use

```
[ToggleStatus]
```

and it will update as you toggle the group visibility.

Comment: ISFILTERED is not decleared within Power BI paginated Reports